# How to force NASM to encode int3 as 0xCC

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, machine-code

I'm trying to assemble the following code with NASM

```
 section .text
 global _start


_start:

mov eax, 1
int 3
```

**Objdump -D** yields:

```
test:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400080 <_start>:
 400080:    b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
 400085:    cd 03                   int    $0x3
```

Interestingly enough, when assembled with GAS, *int 3* is encoded as **0xCC** rather than **cd 03**, why is that?

Comment: note that [one of the reasons MS chose to fill uninitialized memory with 0xCC to aid debugging is because of the `int 3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370274/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `int3` mnemonic for the special one-byte encoding.

```
nasm -l /dev/stdout /tmp/foo.asm
 1 00000000 CD03                    int 3
 2 00000002 CC                      int3
```

---

From the [Intel's insn set manual entry for `int`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/INT_n_INTO_INT_3):

> An interrupt generated by `INTO` or `INT3` (CC) differs from one generated by `INT n` in the following ways:
>
> - The normal IOPL checks do not occur in virtual-8086 mode. The interrupt is taken (without fault) with any IOPL value.
> - The interrupt redirection enabled by the virtual-8086 mode extensions (VME) does not occur. The interrupt is always handled by a protected-mode handler.
>
> These features do not pertain to CD03, the “normal” 2-byte opcode for INT 3

It also says:

> Intel and Microsoft assemblers will not generate the CD03 opcode from any mnemonic

because there aren't any normal / common use-cases for the 2-byte encoding.  NASM keeps it simple and always uses the `CD` opcode for the `int` mnemonic.

When NASM does optimize things like `mov rax, 1` to `mov eax,1`, it's a different opcode that uses the same mnemonic.  IDK if it would have been inconvenient to implement, or if NASM simply decided not to.  It makes sense to think of `int3` as a special instruction, different from `int n`, though, because it's only 1 byte.

Comment: Aside from backward compatibility, what's the point of using **CD03** ?

Comment: @Trey: they behave differently in vm86 mode.  Other than that, probably no reason to ever type `int 3` instead of `int3`, but NASM gives you the option.

Comment: It's a pity they didn't use a different mnemonic (e.g. "`break`") so that the difference between a software interrupt (which is subject to privilege checks and may generate a general protection fault if those checks fail) and a breakpoint exception (which is not a software interrupt and not subject to privilege checks) is more obvious.

Comment: @Brendan: "They" being Intel in this case, right?  Yeah, agreed.

Comment: @Brendan - Lack of foresight, perhaps? The instruction set was designed first, in the 70's. Privilege levels and protection were piggy-backed later, in the 80's. Not many expected this to live long into the next millennium. :-)